# Invoke multiple ConditionalOnProperties in the YAML file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-framework-beans

I couldn't find the solution in any other questions posted here.

I have multiple beans with conditionalOnProperty invoking different beans like below

```
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = 'invoke.bean', havingValue = 'bean1', matchIfMissing = true)
    SupportingInterface bean1() {
        return new Bean1()
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = 'invoke.bean', havingValue = 'bean2')
    SupportingInterface bean2() {
        return new Bean2()
    }
```

in the yml file if I do invoke.bean: bean1 or invoke.bean: bean2 individually works fine but if I want to use both invoke.bean: bean1, bean2 how can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@ConditionalOnProperty for multi-valued properies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969140/conditionalonproperty-for-multi-valued-properies)

Comment: @flyx It partly works but I don't want to invoke both the beans. Example if there are 3 beans it should only invoke the ones that are specified in the application.yml. 

In the application.yml if invoke.bean[0]:bean1 and invoke.bean[1]:bean1 are mentioned it should not load bean3 during the start. How can I get that approach?

Comment: I don't follow. In the question you say that you want to invoke both beans but now you say you don't? The approach in the answer of the linked question should also work with three beans.

Comment: @flyx
    ATBean
    ATConditionalOnProperty(name = 'invoke.bean', havingValue = 'bean1', matchIfMissing = true)
    SupportingInterface bean1() {
        return new Bean1()
    }

    ATBean
    ATConditionalOnProperty(name = 'invoke.bean', havingValue = 'bean2')
    SupportingInterface bean2() {
        return new Bean2()
    }

    ATBean
    ATConditionalOnProperty(name = 'invoke.bean', havingValue = 'bean3')
    SupportingInterface bean3() {
        return new Bean3()
    }
If in config file if I give reference to 2 beans spring should not load bean 3 into context.

Comment: As I said, that should work with the approach in the answer of the linked question.

Comment: I tried the above but if I don't use all three references in config file if is loading the beans. Example if I use email bean in bean2 and something else in bean1 and add reference for bean1 alone it is loading email bean and looking for the config. If I use the Spring ConditionalOnProperty it uses OnPropertyCondition which  checks if properties are defined in environment. If it is not defined it doesn't load at all.

Comment: You should add all the code you're currently using to the question.