# Can't use enumration on @ConditionalOnProperty havingValue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums

Following code won't compile, I get "Attribute value must be constant".

Is there a workaround to get it working?

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "my.property", havingValue = MyEnum.A.name())
public class MyService {
}
```

```
public enum MyEnum {
    A,
    B
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do this with `@ConditionalOnProperty` or with a custom **Conditional** class / annotation like in the example [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37986942/2039546).

You can't send `MyEnum.A` or `MyEnum.A.name()` with `havingValue`, [because compile constants can only be primitives and Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

###### You can do the comparison with **`@ConditionalOnProperty`**:

```java
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(
        name = "my.property", havingValue = "A"
)
public class MyService {}
```

###### Alternatively you can do the comparison with **`@ConditionalOnExpression`:**

```java
@Service
@ConditionalOnExpression(
        value = "#{T(com._75471475.MyEnum).valueOf(\'${my.property}\') == T(com._75471475.MyEnum).A}"
)
public class MyService {}
```